# text search using jquery filter delay during backspace

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jquery filter to search for names in a big list of names. It works just fine with good speed when I type in the input field. But when I press backspace button to clear the search text there is a delay of more then 4s when there are about 2 or 3 characters left.

I have made a demo to explain my problem

```
<input type="text" class="search">
<div class="list"></div>
<script>
        // Get the list div
        let $list = $('.list');
        
        // Form a list of numbers from 1 to 8000
        let listHtml = ''
        for (let i = 0; i < 8000; i++) {
            listHtml += `<div class="list_item"><div class="list_item_value c${i}">${i}</div></div>`;
        }

        $list.html(listHtml);

        // Get all the list items
        $listItem = $list.find('.list_item');


        $('.search').on('keyup', function(e) {
            // Get the search text
            let text = $(this).val();
            $listItem.filter(function() {
                $(this).toggle($(this).find(`.list_item_value`).text().includes(text));
            });
        });
</script>
```

I have simplified my problem with this demo by replacing the text search by number search.

One way to fix this problem would be by canceling the ongoing jquery filter process when a backspace is pressed. But I don't know how to do that. Please someone help me fix it.

Comment: It takes longer to display 8000 items than it does to hide them.   If the problem is that you're pressing backspace multiple times so it appears to take a lot longer, then debounce your keyup (generally a good idea anyway).   You can't "cancel" the filter as it's not asynchronous and js is single-threaded (so there's no way for your "cancel" to fire until the .filter has completed anyway)

Comment: You're also using `.filter` incorrectly (you're using it as `.each`) and show/hiding every item one at a time is very slow.  Instead, return the result of .filter and do a bulk update (show/hide for all items in one go)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  function makeItems(n, t) {
    for (var i = 1; i < n; i++) {
      $(t).append("<div class='list_item'><div class='list_item_value " + i + "'>" + i + "</div>");
    }
  }
  
  var $list = $('.list');
  
  makeItems(8000, $list);

  $('.search').keyup(function(e) {
    var text = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $(".filtered").removeClass("filtered");
    var search = (text.length > 0);
    if (search) {
      $(".list_item", $list).filter(function(index) {
        return $(this).text().indexOf(text) === -1;
      }).addClass("filtered");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.filtered {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="search">
<div class="list"></div>
```

Not too much different from your code. Some reduction of code. When the Search is done, there is a condition to ensure it's not done on an empty value. Also we reset the view each time. Show, Hide, and Toggle have easing and callbacks, so they can be slower at times. Add/Remove class is very quick.

https://ryanpeden.com/javascript-indexof-vs-includes-performance/

> So while `includes` will be a tiny, tiny amount slower because it has to check if you passed it a regex, in reality this will make no difference to how fast your code runs. You should use `indexOf` if you care about where the substring is in the original string. If you don’t care, just call includes because it makes the intent of your code more clear.

In the end, it's your call if you want to use `includes` or `indexOf` for your comparison.